# Many Web Service calls caused 401 Unauthorized response randomly

Tags: web-services, soap, asmx

I have consuming Web Service that's calling another web service. My Application can run a scenario when it makes a lot of calls in short period of time. At some point of time Web Service starts throwing back error 401 Unauthorized. Here's detailed error:

```
<Exception>
    <Source>mscorlib</Source>
    <Message>The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'.</Message>
    <Stack>
Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateAuthentication(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, WebException responseException, HttpChannelFactory`1 factory)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory`1 factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&amp; msgData, Int32 type)
   at KwikTagWebInterface.DMSWebSrv.IWOVServicesSoap.CreateDocuments(CreateDocumentsRequest request)
   at KwikTagWebInterface.DMSWebSrv.WOVServicesSoapClient.CreateDocuments(CreateDocumentsInput CreateDocuments1)
   at KwikTagWebInterface.Controllers.DMSConnector.CreateDocumentProforma(String profIndex, String matter, String userName)
   at KwikTagWebInterface.KTWebServices.TagProformaECover(String profIndex, String matter, String userName, String userDomain)</Stack>
    <InnerException>
      <Source>System</Source>
      <Message>The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.</Message>
      <Stack>   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)</Stack>
    </InnerException>
  </Exception>
```

It throws several errors like this and then continue working just fine. There is absolutely no difference between those calls, so I don't understand why some of them works fine and some of them don't.

Here's my configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="IWOVServicesSoap" maxReceivedMessageSize="2097152" maxBufferSize="2097152" maxBufferPoolSize="2097152">
        <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
          <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
          <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
        </security>
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
    <endpoint address="http://Server/Application/Services/IWOVServices.asmx"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="IWOVServicesSoap"
      contract="WebSrv.IWOVServicesSoap" name="IWOVServicesSoap" />
  </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting throttled, though that's the wrong response code for such a situation. This is the nature of distributed services, though. I'd recommend employing a retry policy of some kind to mitigate the problem. That or introduce some rate limiting of your own to reduce how frequently you make requests. Or, if there is a way to batch your requests and send just 1 instead of 1,000 that would probably be the optimal solution.

Comment: can you please explain how to batch the requests ?